# Swift Array behaviour

Tags: arrays, swift

I have created one class
which look like this

```
class IntegerReference {
    var value = 10
}
```

Then i have allocate array `firstIntegers` which contains `IntegerReference` And anther array `secondIntegersis` just assign reference of `firstIntegers`

```
var firstIntegers = [IntegerReference(), IntegerReference()]
var secondIntegers = firstIntegers
```

Now i want to change the value of `firstIntegers` array

```
firstIntegers[0].value = 100
print(firstIntegers[0].value) //100  it is ok..
print(secondIntegers[0].value) //100 it is ok..
```

But when i want to modify `firstIntegers` array it will not affect on `secondIntegers` array

```
firstIntegers[0] = IntegerReference()
print(firstIntegers[0].value)   //10    it is ok..
print(secondIntegers[0].value) // 100   Why 100? it should be 10 or Not?
```

Comment: Too early in the morning :p. Anyway, thats because `secondIntegers` still has the instance of the first value (`100`). In `firstIntegers[0] = IntegerReference()` you simply replaced the instance in `firstIntegers` but `secondIntegers` is still unaffected. Changing the value of an instance is because it's a `class` rather than having anything to do with an `Array`.

Comment: i had similar answer but @Eendje answered it quite well :P

Comment: Please read the section [Structures and Enumerations Are Value Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html)

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the value in `secondIntegers` changes when you change the value in `firstIntegers` is because `IntegerReference` is a class (example 1).

The moment you replaced the instance in `firstIntegers`, a new instance of `IntegerReference` is placed in `firstIntegers`. But the old instance with the value of `100` is still inside `secondIntegers`, which is why it still prints `100` when accessed (example 2).

To show you what I meant I've created a few examples including the address of the instances.

Data:

```
class Foo { 
    var value = 10 
}

var array1 = [Foo(), Foo()]
var array2 = array1
```

Example 1:

```
array1[0].value = 100

print("address:", getAddress(array1[0]), "value:", array1[0].value)
print("address:", getAddress(array2[0]), "value:", array2[0].value)
```

Output:

> address: 0x000060000002d820 value: 100
>   address: 0x000060000002d820 value: 100

Example 2:

```
array1[0] = Foo()

print("address:", getAddress(array1[0]), "value:", array1[0].value)
print("address:", getAddress(array2[0]), "value:", array2[0].value)
```

Output:

> address: **0x000060800002c120** value: 10
>   address: 0x000060000002d820 value: 100

Edit:

In case you wonder how I got the address:

```
func getAddress(_ object: AnyObject) -> UnsafeMutableRawPointer {
    return Unmanaged.passUnretained(object).toOpaque()
}
```

Comment: You might want to add the definition of `getAddress()`, it is not part of the standard library.

Comment: Yea, but I thought since the main point is to show the address so I left that part out for better readability.